# Totally Invertible Submatrices

Tags: code-golf, matrix, decision-problem, linear-algebra

*(inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1886327) over on Math)*

#### The Definitions

Given an `n x n` square matrix **A**, we can call it [`invertible`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) if there exists some `n x n` square matrix **B** such that **AB** = **BA** = **I<sub>n</sub>**, with **I<sub>n</sub>** being the identity matrix of size `n x n` (the matrix with the main diagonal `1`s and anything else `0`), and **AB** and **BA** representing usual [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) (I won't go into that here - go take a linear algebra class).

From that, we can call an `m x n` matrix **C** `totally invertible` if every `k x k` submatrix (defined below) of **C** is invertible for all `k > 1`, `k <= (smaller of m,n)`.

A submatrix is defined as the resulting matrix after deletion of any number of rows and/or columns from the original matrix. For example, the below `3x3` matrix **C** can be transformed into a `2x2` submatrix **C'** by removing the first row `1 2 3` and the middle column `2 5 8` as follows:

```
C = [[1 2 3]
     [4 5 6]    -->  C' = [[4 6]
     [7 8 9]]              [7 9]]
```

Note that there are many different submatrix possibilities, the above is just an example. This challenge is only concerned with those where the resulting submatrix is a `k x k` *square matrix*.

#### The Challenge

Given an input matrix, determine if it is totally invertible or not.

#### The Input

- A single matrix of size `m x n`, in [any suitable format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Without loss of generality, you can assume `m <= n` or `m >= n`, whichever is golfier for your code, and take the input that way (i.e., you get a [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) operation for free if you want it).
- The input matrix size will be no smaller than `3 x 3`, and no larger than your language can handle.
- The input matrix will consist of only numeric values from **Z<sup>+</sup>** (the [positive integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)).

#### The Output

- A [truthy/falsey](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/42963) value for whether the input matrix is totally invertible.

#### The Rules

- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### The Examples

```
Truthy

[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 1]
 [3 1 2]]

[[2 6 3]
 [1 12 2]
 [5 3 1]]

[[1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 4 1]
 [3 4 1 2]]

[[2  3  5  7  11]
 [13 17 19 23 29]
 [31 37 41 43 47]]


Falsey

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

[[1 6 2 55 3]
 [4 5 5 5  6]
 [9 3 7 10 4]
 [7 1 8 23 9]]

[[2 3 6]
 [1 2 12]
 [1 1 6]]

[[8 2 12 13 2]
 [12 7 13 12 13]
 [8 1 12 13 5]]
```

Comment: Where is the singular submatrix in `2 6 3; 1 12 2; 5 3 1`?

Comment: @feersum Whoops - thanks for the catch. That was supposed to have gone under Truthy and the one below it was supposed to be a `6` in the corner, not a `7`. Clumsy typos.

Comment: At first, I thought the title said "totally invertible submarines".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>26 24 23 20 19 17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to @miles (unnecessary for each, `€`, when taking determinants)
-2 bytes, @miles again! (unnecessary chain separation, and use of `Ð€` quick)

```
ZœcLÆḊ
œcÐ€JÇ€€Ȧ
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=WsWTY0zDhuG4igrFk2PDkOKCrErDh-KCrOKCrMim&input=&args=W1s4LCAyLCAxMiwgMTMsIDJdLAogWzEyLCA3LCAxMywgMTIsIDEzXSwKIFs4LCAxLCAxMiwgMTMsIDVdXQ)** or [all 8 tests](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=WsWTY0zDhuG4igrFk2PDkOKCrErDh-KCrOKCrMimCsOH4oKs&input=&args=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)

#### How?

```
œcÐ€JÇ€€Ȧ  - Main link: matrix as an array, M
    J      - range of length -> [1,2,...,len(a)] (n)
  Ð€       - for each of right argument
œc         -     combinations of M numbering n
     Ç€€   - call the last link (1) as a monad for €ach for €ach
        Ȧ  - all truthy (any determinant of zero results in 0, otherwise 1)
                 (this includes an implicit flattening of the list)

ZœcLÆḊ - Link 1, determinants of sub-matrices: row selection, s
Z      - transpose s
   L   - length of s
 œc    - combinations of transposed s numbering length of s
    ÆḊ - determinant
```

Comment: I was thinking I needed it because I have a bunch of combinations, but no I do not need to instruct to explicitly. Thanks!

Comment: I learned about it from that last challenge using determinants, and verified that it indeed does have `ldepth = 2` in the source

Comment: Also I think you can save a byte in link 2 using `ZœcLÆḊ` and another byte in the main link by `çÐ€JȦ`

Comment: Good stuff @miles thanks again! I thought that the first of those two did not work when I tried it, but it must have been when I was using the `€` you golfed off. Totally forgot about `Ð€`.

Comment: @miles ...and that gets another byte off by allowing me to combine main and the link before it.

Comment: Nice combining, I think you can make it a one liner if you want with `œcÐ€JµZœcLÆḊµ€€Ȧ` which is also 16 bytes

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica 10.0, 34 bytes

```
#~Minors~n~Table~{n,Tr@#}~FreeQ~0&
```

A 6-tilde chain... new personal record!

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 57 bytes

```
tZyt:Y@!"@w2)t:Y@!"@w:"3$t@:)w@:)w3$)0&|H*XHx]J)]xxtZy]H&
```

Of course, you can [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFp5dDpZQCEiQHcyKXQ6WUAhIkB3OiIzJHRAOil3QDopdzMkKTAmfEgqWEh4XUopXXh4dFp5XUgm&input=WzEgMiAzOzIgMyAxOzMgMSAyXQ)

Input should be in 'portrait' orientation (nRows>=nColumns). I feel that this may not be the most efficient solution... But at least I'm leaving some room for others to outgolf me. I would love to hear specific hints that could have made this particular approach shorter, but I think this massive bytecount should inspire others to make a MATL entry with a completely different approach. Displays 0 if falsy, or a massive value if truthy (will quickly become Inf if matrix too large; for 1 extra byte, one could replace `H*` with `H&Y` (logical and)). Saved a few bytes thanks to @LuisMendo.

```
tZy  % Duplicate, get size. Note that n=<m.   
%   STACK:  [m n], [C]
t: % Range 1:m                           
%   STACK:  [1...m], [m n], [C]
Y@   % Get all permutations of that range. 
%   STACK:  [K],[m n],[C] with K all perms in m direction.
!"   % Do a for loop over each permutation.
%   STACK:  [m n],[C], current permutation in @.
@b   % Push current permutation. Bubble size to top.
%   STACK:  [m n],[pM],[C] with p current permutation in m direction.
2)t:Y@!" % Loop over all permutations again, now in n direction
%   STACK: [n],[pM],[C] with current permutation in @.
@w:" % Push current permutation. Loop over 1:n (to get size @ x @ matrices)
%   STACK: [pN],[pM],[C] with loop index in @.
3$t  % Duplicate the entire stack.
%   STACK: [pN],[pM],[C],[pN],[pM],[C]
@:)  % Get first @ items from pN
%   STACK: [pNsub],[pM],[C],[pN],[pM],[C]
w@:) % Get first @ items from pM
%   STACK: [pMsub],[pNsub],[C],[pN],[pM],[C]
w3$)  % Get submatrix. Needs a `w` to ensure correct order.
%   STACK: [Csub],[pN],[pM],[C]
0&|  % Determinant.
%   STACK: [det],[pN],[pM],[C]
H*XHx% Multiply with clipboard H.
%   STACK: [pN],[pM],[C]
]    % Quit size loop
%   STACK: [pN],[pM],[C]. Expected: [n],[pM],[C]
J)   % Get last element from pN, which is n.
%   STACK: [n],[pM],[C]
]    % Quit first loop
xxtZy% Reset stack to
%   STACK: [m n],[C]
]    % Quit final loop.
H& % Output H only.
```