# Dutch Burgerservicenummer (BSN) eleven-test

Tags: code-golf, string, arithmetic, decision-problem

#### Introduction:

A Dutch BSN (BurgerServiceNummer) is valid when it complies to the following rules:

- It only contains digits.
- The length should be either 8 or 9 in length.
- When the digits are indexed as `A` through `I`, the result of the following sum: `9xA + 8xB + 7xC + 6xD + 5xE + 4xF + 3xG + 2xH + -1xI` (NOTE the -1 instead of 1!) should be divisible by 11, and should not be 0.

#### Challenge:

**Input:** A string or char-array representing the BSN.

**Output:** A [truthy or falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) result whether the input is a valid BSN.

#### Challenge Rules:

- The input format should be a string or char-array. You are not allowed to use an int-array of digits, or a (possibly octal) number. (You are allowed to convert it to an int-array of digits yourself, though, but not directly as argument.)
- Despite the restriction on the input above, you can assume all test cases will contain one or more digits (`[0-9]+`)
- Regarding the BSN with length 8 instead of 9, the Dutch Wikipedia states the following: "*For the eleven-test and for other practical uses, a leading zero is added to make the number of length 9.*" ([source](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgerservicenummer#cite_note-2))

#### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

#### Test cases:

```
// Truthy test cases:
111222333
123456782
232262536
010464554
10464554
44016773

// Falsey test cases:
000000000
192837465
247594057
88888888
73
3112223342
000000012
```

Comment: Is it true that if there are 8 digits, one omits `A` from the formula given?

Comment: @isaacg I've added the rule regarding this with a link to the (Dutch) wikipedia page. You are indeed right, it omits `A` from the formula (or basically adds a leading `0` to make it length 9, resulting in the same result as omitting `A`).

Comment: Test case for "sum [...] should not be 0.": 000000012

Comment: @betseg I've added it to the list

Comment: Hi! I'm doing my solution in python, and am wondering about clarification of truthy and falsey. Python counts the integer `0` as falsey and any other integer as truthy, and my current solution always converts to bools?

Comment: @StephenUniverse I assume you're talking about [the standard for truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210)? In which case `0` as falsey and any other integer as truthy for Python is indeed fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I've been since browsing other answers, and it seems like that's what people are indeed doing.

Comment: Note that most answers do accept a `0` padded number like `000000073`, which is technically not a valid number. The rule "The length should be either 8 or 9 in length." should be interpreted as non-zero padded.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Although you're correct for actual BSN numbers, in this challenge I do accept `0`-padded numbers as input. E.g., the truthy test case `010464554` or falsey test cases `000000000` and `000000012` are examples of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
`()DgLR*OD11Ö89¹gåP0Ê
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=YCgpRGdMUipPRDExw5Y4OcK5Z8OlUDDDig&input=MTA0NjQ1NTQ) or as a [Test suite](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=fHZ5YCgpRGdMUipPRDExw5Y4OXlnw6VQMMOKLA&input=MTExMjIyMzMzCjEyMzQ1Njc4MgoyMzIyNjI1MzYKMDEwNDY0NTU0CjEwNDY0NTU0CjQ0MDE2NzczCjAwMDAwMDAwMAoxOTI4Mzc0NjUKMjQ3NTk0MDU3Cjg4ODg4ODg4CjczCjMxMTIyMjMzNDI)

**Explanation**

```
`                        # push input as individual chars onto stack
 (                       # negate top value
  )                      # wrap in list
   DgLR                  # range [len(input) ... 1]
       *O                # multiply with list of digits and sum
         D11Ö            # is evenly divisible by 11
             89¹gå       # len(input) is 8 or 9
                  P      # product of sum/divisible by 11/len in (8,9)
                   0Ê    # not equal to 0
```

Comment: Probably due to an older version of 05AB1E, but you can save 3 bytes now by changing `DgL` to `ā` and `0Ê` to `Ā`. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/QUPzSGOQlr@LoeHhaRaWh3amH14acKTh/39DAxMzE1NTEwA)

Comment: `89` should actually be `89S`, since an input with length 89 could potentially give a false-positive.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6) 57

Input as an array of chars. `reduceRight` saves the day!

```js
s=>!(i=1,t=s.reduceRight((t,v)=>t-v*++i),!t|t%11|(i|1)-9)
```

**Test**

```js
F=
s=>!(i=1,t=s.reduceRight((t,v)=>t-v*++i),!t|t%11|(i|1)-9)


;['111222333','123456782','232262536','010464554','10464554','44016773']
.forEach(t=>{
  var r=F([...t]);console.log(t,r)
})

;['000000000','192837465','247594057','88888888','73','3112223342','3112223342']
.forEach(t=>{
  var r=F([...t]);console.log(t,r)
})
```

Comment: Always nice to see a `reduceRight` answer!

Comment: Finally found a way to reach 58 with `map()`, just to realize that your answer is actually _57_ bytes long :-)

Comment: @Arnauld yep I can't believe I counted wrong *again*, thanks

Answer (score 8):

### R, <strike>86</strike> 67 bytes

Edit: Thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam for suggesting the dot product!

```
l=length(x<-scan(,""));s=as.double(x)%*%c(l:2,-1);!s%%11&s&l>7&l<10
```

Reads input from stdin and store as an array/vector of characters. Subsequently convert to numeric,multiply with the vector `9...2,-1` and check all conditions.

Comment: Does not work for me. You should split `x` as vector.

Comment: @djhurio Enter the values separated by space and they are implicitly stored in a vector of characters. Alternatively enter them one by one by hitting enter in between.

Comment: `if(l<9)x=c(0,x);s=sum(as.double(x)*c(9:2,-1))` can be turned into `s=sum(as.double(x)*c(l:2,-1))`. Also, the sum of the pairwise product of two vectors is the same as their dot-multiplication `%*%`.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Nice! The dot product is really clever.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>61</s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

Takes an array of chars as input. Returns `false` / `true`.

```js
a=>!(a.map(c=>s-=--k?-c*k-c:c,k=a.length&9,s=0)|!s|k|s%11)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>!(a.map(c=>s-=--k?-c*k-c:c,k=a.length&9,s=0)|!s|k|s%11)

// truthy
console.log(f([..."111222333"]));
console.log(f([..."123456782"]));
console.log(f([..."232262536"]));
console.log(f([..."010464554"]));
console.log(f([..."10464554"]));
console.log(f([..."44016773"]));

// falsy
console.log(f([..."000000000"]));
console.log(f([..."192837465"]));
console.log(f([..."247594057"]));
console.log(f([..."88888888"]));
console.log(f([..."73"]));
console.log(f([..."3112223342"]));
```

Answer (score 6):

### C, <s>112</s> <s>101</s> <s>96</s> <s>98</s> 104 bytes

*Thanks to @MartinEnder for saving <s>5</s> 3 bytes <s>while fixing my code</s>!*

```
j,i,k,l;f(char*s){l=strlen(s);for(i=l,j=k=0;j<l;)k+=(s[j++]-48)*(i>1?i--:-1);return!(k%11)&&k&&(l^8)<2;}
```

Returns 0 if invalid, 1 if valid. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#DcVLDoIwEADQvbeQhGYG2sQpLohD9SBGE6IQ@rGaFleEs6Nv8zYnrfQy8AiPqU9VxiWYPKcwRMjI4zuBNUE6482BXRcYfW0gX11d39SxxQrsmS5WqZMi5DTM3xT34EsiFMILAeHeYqd53b16GwGXT7JxHqEon4X8R0Ra66ZpCkRet@0H)

Comment: This accepts `61` even though it is not of correct length.

Comment: This does not work with my personal BSN.

Comment: Hopefully fixed.

Comment: Not fixed. Doesn't work with mine either.

Comment: I'm still not a valid Dutch citizen according to this :(. I can PM you my BSN if needed.

Comment: @Roberrrt, @DavidPostill; is it OK now or should I just give up? =(

Comment: It returns a 1 for mine now :)!

Comment: `!(k%11)` and `(l^8)<2` are both always `0` or `1`, so you can change one `&&` to `&`: `!(k%11)&(l^8)<2&&k`.

Comment: Turning this into a recursive function makes it 100 bytes: `i,k;f(char*s){*s?f(s+1),k+=i*(*s-48),!++i?i=2:0:0;}g(char*s){i=-1;k=0;f(s);return!(k%11)&i-9u<2&&k;}` That's because `l` can be avoided when it can be inferred from `i`.

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>95</s> <s>79</s> 93 bytes

```
function(x){y=as.double(el(strsplit(x,"")));z=y%*%c((q<-length(y)):2,-1);(z&!z%%11&q>7&q<10)}
```

Unnamed function that takes a string as argument. At first I overread the requirement of having a string as input instead of a number, but that's good, because it saves some bytes on conversion.

I am not sure how to interpret the array of characters, but if that means that you can use a vector of stringed digits `"1" "2" "3" "4" etc` as input, it becomes a bit shorter even:

```
function(x){y=as.double(x);z=y%*%c((q<-length(y)):2,-1);(z&!z%%11&q>7&q<10)}
```

Splits x into a numeric vector, then appends a 0 if length is 8, then calculates the dotproduct of vector y and `c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,-1)`. Tests if the result is both nonzero and divisible by 11.

Saved 16 bytes thanks to the logic by @Emigna, implicitly appending the 0 in the creation of the vector `c(length(x):2,-1)`.

Forgot to add check for length 8/9, so +14 bytes :(

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 58 bytes (52 + 6)

```
@N=(-1,2..9);$r+=$_*shift@N for reverse@F;$_=$r&&/^\d{8,9}$/&&!($r%11)
```

Run with

```
perl -F// -lapE
```

Input passed through `STDIN`:

***Usage***

```
echo 232262536 | perl -F// -lapE '@N=(-1,2..9);$r+=$_*shift@N for reverse@F;$_=$r&&/^\d{8,9}$/&&!($r%11)'
```

---

Outputs `1` for as the truthy value, `0` or nothing for falsey values.

Comment: You can save some bytes at the beginning: `$r+=$_*(-1,2..9)[$i++]for reverse@F`. Also, `-F -pe` (and input supplied without final newline, with `echo -n` for instance) is enough (unless your Perl is too old, in which case you'll need `-a` (but on recent Perls, it's implied by `-F`). Finally, your code was 70 bytes long, not 52 ;)

Answer (score 3):

## C++14, <s>107</s> 106 bytes

-1 byte for `int` instead of `auto` in for loop.

As unnamed lambda returning via reference parameter. Requires input to be `std::string` or a container of char, like `vector<char>`.

```c++
[](auto c,int&r){int i=c.size();r=7<i&&i<10?-2*c.back()+96:~1<<9;for(int x:c)r+=(x-48)*i--;r=r%11<1&&r>0;}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

auto f=
[](auto c, int& r){
 int i = c.size();
 //if the size is correct, init r to -2*I so we can add I safely later
 //otherwise such a big negative number, that the final test fails
 r = 7<i && i<10 ? -2*c.back()+96 : ~1<<9;
 for (auto x:c)
  r += (x-48)*i--;
 r = r%11<1 && r>0;
}
;

using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals;

int main(){
 int r;
 f("111222333"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("123456782"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("010464554"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("10464554"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("44016773"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::endl;
 f("000000000"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("192837465"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("73"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("88888888"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("3112222342"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::endl;
 f("99999999"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
 f("999999999"s,r); std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
V€U×JN1¦µL:2=4×Sµ11ḍa
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=VuKCrFXDl0pOMcKmwrVMOjI9NMOXU8K1MTHhuI1h&input=&args=IjExMTIyMjMzMyI)** or [run all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=VuKCrFXDl0pOMcKmwrVMOjI9NMOXU8K1MTHhuI1hCsW8w4figqxL4oKsWQ&input=&args=WyIxMTEyMjIzMzMiLCIxMjM0NTY3ODIiLCIyMzIyNjI1MzYiLCIwMTA0NjQ1NTQiLCIxMDQ2NDU1NCIsIjQ0MDE2NzczIiwiMDAwMDAwMDAwIiwiMTkyODM3NDY1IiwiMjQ3NTk0MDU3IiwiODg4ODg4ODgiLCI3MyIsIjMxMTIyMjMzNDIiXQ)

Truthy return values are non-zero (and are, in fact, the multiple of 11 sum).

#### How?

```
V€U×JN1¦µL:2=4×Sµ11ḍa - Main link: string of digits  e.g. "111222333"
V€                    - eval each - effectively cast each to an integer (keeps leading zeros)
  U                   - upend                        e.g. [ 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
    J                 - range(length)                e.g. [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   ×                  - multiply                     e.g. [ 3, 6, 9, 8,10,12, 7, 8, 9]
      1¦              - apply to index 1 (first element)
     N                -     negate                   e.g. [-3, 6, 9, 8,10,12, 7, 8, 9]
        µ             - monadic chain separation   e.g. z=[-3, 6, 9, 8,10,12, 7, 8, 9]
         L            - length(z)                    e.g. 9
          :2          - integer divide by 2          e.g. 4
            =4        - equals 4?                    e.g. 1
               S      - sum(z)                       e.g. 66
              ×       - multiply                     e.g. 66
                µ     - monadic chain separation   e.g. z=66
                 11ḍ  - divides(11, z)               e.g. 1
                    a - and z (for z=0 case)         e.g. 66 (truthy)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one answer instead of two, since yours has the same 21 byte-count as [_@Emigna_'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102487/52210). But since _Enigma_ answered sooner (and his edit for 21 bytes was also sooner) I've accepted his.

Comment: That sounds fair to me!

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>116</s> <s>112</s> 102 bytes

```
f x=div(length x)2==4&&g x>0&&h x
h=((==0).(`mod`11)).g
g=sum.zipWith(*)(-1:[2..]).map(read.(:[])).reverse
```

`g` counts the sum used in the eleven-proef of `h`, while `f` also checks for the correct length and that the eleven-proef is not 0. Especially the checks of `f` take a lot of bytes.

EDIT: saved 10 bytes thanks to Lynn and `div` rounding down.

Comment: How about `f x=div(length x)2==4&&g x>0&&h x`?

Comment: @Lynn: that is a nice one, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge, 72 bytes

```
>+~>:0`v
^1\-*68_\2/4-!00p*8>1-10p\910gv
@.!+!\%+56:*g00$  _^#!:g01+*-<<
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Pit-PjowYHYKXjFcLSo2OF9cMi80LSEwMHAqOD4xLTEwcFw5MTBndgpALiErIVwlKzU2OipnMDAkICBfXiMhOmcwMSsqLTw8&input=MTExMjIyMzMz)

**Explanation**

```
>+~>:0`v            Read characters from stdin until EOF, converting each digit into
^1\-*68_              a number on the stack, and keeping a count of the characters read.

      \2/4-!00p     Save !(count/2-4), which is only true for valid lengths (8 and 9).
               *    Multiply the EOF (-1) with the final digit; this is the initial total.

8>1-10p\910gv       Loop over the remaining 8 digits, multiplying each of them by 9-i and
 ^#!:g01+*-<<         add to the total; i goes from 7 down to 0, so 9-i goes from 2 to 9.

               $    Drop the loop counter.
           *g00     Multiply total by the length calculation (invalid lengths become 0).
      %+65:         Make a copy of the total, and calculate modulo 11.
    !\              Boolean not the other copy to check for zero. 
  !+                !(total%11 + !(total)) is only true for non-zero multiples of 11.
@.                  Output the result and exit.
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 36 bytes

Not the [longest MATL program I've ever written](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97341/32352), but I like how `if`/`else` statements get very lengthy very quickly in golfing languages. I feel that this solution may not be optimal in MATL, but as of yet I can't optimize it any further. I'm thinking of using the double 0 somewhere, and maybe cut down on the `t`'s everywhere.

```
48-tn8=?0wh]tn9=?P[a2:9]*st11\~Y&}x0
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NDgtdG44PT8wd2hddG45PT9QW2EyOjldKnN0MTFcflkmfXgw&input=JzExMTIyMjMzMyc) Explanation:

```
48-                                  % Subtract 48 (ASCII '0')
   tn                                % Duplicate. Get length.
     8=?                             % If length equals 8
        0wh                          %     Prepend 0 to the duplicate
           ]                         % End if.
            t                        % Duplicate again.
             n9=?                    % If length equals 9.
                 P                   %     Reverse the duplicate
                  [a2:9]*            %     Element-wise product with [-1 2 ... 9]
                         s           %     Sum
                          t11\       %     Duplicate sum, modulus 11
                              ~Y&    %     Result on stack: modulus==0 AND sum!=0
                                 }   % Else
                                  x0 %     Remove the duplicate. Put 0 on stack.
                                     % Display implicitly.
```

Comment: If you can make do with a column vector: `!U` instead of `48-`

Comment: [Beat ya](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102485/dutch-burgerservicenummer-bsn-eleven-test/102522#102522) :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Too bad. `[a2:9]*` results in a non-element-wise multiplication, so another `!` would be needed which would offset the initial gain.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 26 bytes

```
!UGg*R!s0&)s-t11\~Gn8-tg=v
```

The result is a non-empty column vector, which is [truthy iff all its entries are nonzero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398).

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IVVHZypSIXMwJilzLXQxMVx-R244LXRnPXY&input=JzExMTIyMjMzMyc)

Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFhLCiFVS2cqUiFzMCYpcy10MTFcfktuOC10Zz12CiFEVA&input=JzExMTIyMjMzMycKJzEyMzQ1Njc4MicKJzIzMjI2MjUzNicKJzAxMDQ2NDU1NCcKJzEwNDY0NTU0JwonNDQwMTY3NzMnCicwMDAwMDAwMDAnCicxOTI4Mzc0NjUnCicyNDc1OTQwNTcnCic4ODg4ODg4OCcKJzczJwonMzExMjIyMzM0MicKJzAwMDAwMDAxMic) with each result on a different line.

#### Explanation

This tests the three conditions in the following order:

1. Weighted sum is nonzero;
2. Weighted sum is dividible by 11;
3. Length is 8 or 9.

Consider input `'8925'` for the explanation. `;` is the row separator for matrices.

```
!     % Implicit input. Transpose into a column vecvtor
      % STACK: ['8'; '9'; '2'; '5']
U     % Convert each digit to number
      % STACK: [8; 9; 2; 5]
Gg    % Push a row array of ones as long as the input
      % STACK: [8; 9; 2; 5], [1 1 1 1]
*     % Multiply, element-wise with broadcast
      % STACK: [8 8 8 8; 9 9 9 9; 2 2 2 2; 5 5 5 5]
R     % Upper triangular part
      % STACK: [8 8 8 8; 0 9 9 9; 0 0 2 2; 0 0 0 5]
!     % Transpose
      % STACK: [8 0 0 0;8 9 0 0;8 9 2 0;8 9 2 5]
s     % Sum of each column. This multiplies last element by 1, second-last by 2 etc
      % STACK: [32 27 4 5]
0&)   % Split into last element and remaining elements
      % STACK: 5, [32 27 4]
s     % Sum of array
      % STACK: 5, 63
-     % Subtract
      % STACK: -58. This is the result of condition 1
t11\  % Duplicate. Modulo 11
      % STACK: -58, 8
~     % Logical negation
      % STACK: -58, 0. This gives condition 2
Gn    % Push numnber of entries in the input
      % STACK: -58, 0, 4
8-    % Subtract 8. For valid lengths (8 or 9) this gives 0 or 1
      % STACK: -58, 0, -4
tg    % Duplicate. Convert to logical: set nonzero values to 1
      % STACK: -58, 0, -4, 1
=     % 1 if equal, 0 otherwise. Lenghts 8 or 9 will give 1. This is condition 3
      % STACK: -58, 0, 0
v     % Vertically concatenate the entire stack. This is truthy iff all values 
      % are non-zero. Implicitly display
      % STACK: [-58; 0; 0]
```

Comment: Well done. I figured that an approach without `?` would probably be more efficient, but I couldn't figure out how to shorten the length 8 or 9. Your `Gn8-tg=` is very clever.

Comment: By the way, wouldn't a column vector input qualify as a *char-array representing the BSN*, saving you the first `!`?

Comment: @Sanchises The problem is that then `G` pushes a column vector and I need to transpose it to do the repetition with `g*`

Comment: Oh right of course. Never mind!

Answer (score 3):

### PHP <s>139</s> 128 bytes

```
 $u=-1;$i=$argv[1];while($u<=strlen($i)){$c+=($u*(substr($i,-(abs($u)),1)));$u +=$u<0?3:1;}echo($c>0&&!($c%11)&&$u>8&&$u<11?1:0);
```

Could not get the CLI to just echo the true of false. Had to make do it this way. Any ideas?

128 bytes: Turned "true" and "false" to 1 and 0.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 96 bytes

```
param($n)$i=8-($n.count-eq8);!(($b=($n|%{(-"$_",(($i+1)*+"$_"))[!!$i--]})-join'+'|iex)%11)-and$b
```

OK, I'll admit, this looks like a complete mess. And it kinda is. But, bear with me and we'll get through it.

We take input `$n` (as a `char`-array) and set `$i` equal to `8` minus a Boolean value for whether there are 8 items in `$n`. Meaning, if there are 8 items, then `$i` would be `7`.

The next section combines the calculation with our output. Working from the inside, we loop through `$n` with `$n|%{...}`. Each iteration, we use a pseudo-ternary to come up with one of two results -- either `-"$_"` or `(($i+1)*+"$_")`. The index is based on whether `$i` is `0` or not (i.e., we've hit the `-1xI` case from the challenge equation), which gets post-decremented for the next go-round. Those are all gathered up in parens and `-join`ed together with `+`. For example, with input `111222333` at this point we'd have `9+8+7+12+10+8+9+6+-3`. That is piped to `iex` (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`) before being stored into `$b`. We then take that `%11` and perform a Boolean-not `!(...)` on that (i.e., so if it is divisible by 11, this portion is `$true`). That's coupled with `-and$b` to ensure that `$b` is non-zero. That Boolean result is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 111222333,123456782,232262536,010464554,10464554,44016773|%{"$_ -> "+(.\dutch-burgerservicenummer.ps1 ([char[]]"$_"))}
111222333 -> True
123456782 -> True
232262536 -> True
10464554 -> True
10464554 -> True
44016773 -> True

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 000000000,192837465,247594057,88888888,73,3112223342,000000012|%{"$_ -> "+(.\dutch-burgerservicenummer.ps1 ([char[]]"$_"))}
0 -> False
192837465 -> False
247594057 -> False
88888888 -> False
73 -> False
3112223342 -> False
12 -> False
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>111</s> <s>110</s> 104 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@Kevin-cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)*

*-6 bytes by reading the rules (yay)*

```python
lambda s:len(s)in(8,9)and not(x:=sum(a:=[*map(lambda n,m:int(n)*m,s[::-1],range(1,10))])-2*a[0])%11and x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/NboMwEITveQpfEDYikX8xscSpj0E5uAohSOAg20jJ09PYuFXbQ/c0K83sfrM8/e1uWL3YbWjet0nPHxcNnJp6Ax0aDazLM9LmAszdw4dq3DpDrZq2mPUCk9uUsxqNhwYVc@lapY6kK602Qw9JSTBCHTrSQre4Qxkh4dhju94t8Hb1tycYDWhzQgillDGWlyAnlHFRyZqGhTJKKypYFRZMMK@4EDzafmjOMamkZHmnDuA12rneejDA/Ql6Wd6060HmwGWMbYDt/WpNojjlIEsy5hcbGn3H0eEQiK96cn0ixl8TUc60ZpJXIhJzKc4cCxmWOk3QMrZjqSqP9dIRQv@QB8IB7g//od8NkX6Xv@hTHG2f)

There's probably more golfing to do, but this is what I have for now.

Comment: You can remove the space at `11and` for -1 byte. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 102 bytes

```python
def f(i):S=sum(a*b for a,b in zip([-1]+range(2,10),map(int,i)[::-1]));return(7<len(i)<10)*(S%11<1)*S>0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 96 bytes

```python
def g(s):u=7<len(s)<10and sum(x*int(('0'+s)[-x])for x in range(2,10))-int(s[-1]);print(u%11<1)*u
```

Takes a string as input.  The function adds a `'0'` to the front of the string whether it needs it or not, and uses Python's negative indices to add elements, starting from the end of the string and working back-to-front.

The `-1xI` is handled separately, using a second call to `int()`.  I couldn't figure out how to avoid this without costing more bytes than I saved.

`def g(s):u=7<len(s)<10and sum(x*int(('0'+s)[-x])for x in range(10))-2*int(s[-1]);print(u%11<1)*u` would work just as well, since it would add `1` times `s[-1]` but then subtract it twice, and it would also add `0` times (something) which of course wouldn't affect the sum.

Comment: [92 bytes (Python 3.8)](https://tio.run/##fY/NbsIwEITvPMVekG0Kldc/cUBw6mNQDq4SQiQwyHYkePoUO27V9tA5zUizu9/eHvF0dbK@@bHbvY9ne/loLIQNpcNmZ7bn1tHAtsitayAMF3pf9C5SSjh5CWy/uh/Y8erhDr0Db13XUrFEztgqtcJ@hQfG5ohbZIthTM3oh3h6pPqeIKIQQkpJlkBQSKUrU4sUhBSiElpWKXDkqlJaq1z74ZXiWBkjyWEzg6dsCK2P0NHpCHtW3mxoYR6g6Rtw1wi@jYN3heKVwLzYPH/zifp7nM1mifhoz6EtxPxLGWUtamlUpTOxMnqtuDYp1EXJm/ydLK@q/F5ZguIPeSLs6HTwH/qpkOkn@4u@jLPxEw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 345 Bytes

Includes +3 for `-a`

```
([]){{}({}[((((()()()){}){}){}){}]<>)<>([])}{}<>([][(()()()()){}]){({}[()]){([]){{}{}([])}}}{}([{}])({}({}){})({}({})({}){})({}(({}){}){})({}(({})({})){}{})({}(({})({}){}){})({}((({}))({}){}){}{})({}((({}){}){}){})(({}(((({})){}){}){}{}{}<(((()()())()){}{})>)){{}({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{}[{}]<(())>){((<{}{}>))}{}(<()>)}{}
```

Truthy is 1, Falsy has a 0 on the top of the stack.

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdKXt7fSh7fVsoKCgoKCkoKSgpKXt9KXt9KXt9KXt9XTw-KTw-KFtdKX17fTw-KFtdWygoKSgpKCkoKSl7fV0peyh7fVsoKV0peyhbXSl7e317fShbXSl9fX17fShbe31dKSh7fSh7fSl7fSkoe30oe30pKHt9KXt9KSh7fSgoe30pe30pe30pKHt9KCh7fSkoe30pKXt9e30pKHt9KCh7fSkoe30pe30pe30pKHt9KCgoe30pKSh7fSl7fSl7fXt9KSh7fSgoKHt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KSgoe30oKCgoe30pKXt9KXt9KXt9e317fTwoKCgoKSgpKCkpKCkpe317fSk-KSl7e30oe30oPD4pKTw-eygoe30pKXsoe31bKCldKTw-fXt9fXt9PD4oW3t9KClde31be31dPCgoKSk-KXsoKDx7fXt9PikpfXt9KDwoKT4pfXt9&input=MDAwMDAwMDEy&args=LWE)

I'm pretty sure there is a shorter way to do the multiplication in a loop, but I haven't found it yet.

```
#reverse and subtract 48 from all numbers (ASCII -> decimal)
([]){{}({}[((((()()()){}){}){}){}]<>)<>([])}{}<> 

([][(()()()()){}])       #height - 8
{({}[()]){               #if not 0 subtract 1
   ([]){{}{}([])}        #if still not 0 pop everything
}}{}                     #this loop pops everything unless there are 8 or 9 digits

([{}])                   # -I
({}({}){})               # H*2
({}({})({}){})           # G*3
({}(({}){}){})           # F*4
({}(({})({})){}{})       # E*5
({}(({})({}){}){})       # D*6
({}((({}))({}){}){}{})   # C*7
({}((({}){}){}){})       # B*8
(({}(((({})){}){}){}{}{} # A*9 pushed twice with:
<(((()()())()){}{})>))   # 11 under it


{{} #if not 0
({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{}   # mod 11
[{}]<(())>){((<{}{}>))}{}                       # logical not
(<()>)                                          # push 0 to exit loop
}{}
                                                # implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>120</s> 115 bytes

This loops through the `char[]` it receives as input and returns true or false:

```
bool b(char[]n){int r=0,k,i=0,l=n.Length;for(;i<l;i++){k=i==l-1?-1:l-i;r+=k*(n[i]-48);}return r>0&r%11<1&l<10&l>7;}
```

Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Kaxrt

I'm sure I can scrape out a few bytes, especially in the messy `return`. Any ideas welcome!

Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to Kevin. I had no idea I could use `&` instead of `&&`!

Comment: +1! `r>0&&r%11==0&&l<10&&l>7` can be golfed to `r>0&r%11<1&l<10&l>7` (`&&` to `&` and `r%11==0` to `r%11<1`). And `-'0'` can be golfed to `-48`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>115</s> <s>98</s> 94 bytes

```java
b->{int l=b.length,i=l,r=0;for(;l>7&l<10&i-->0;)r-=(b[i]-48)*(l-i<2?1:i-l);return r>0&r%11<1;}
```

I'm surprised no one has posted a Java answer yet, so here is one.

-4 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nZJfa8IwFMXf/RRBmLTDlPxrU1fbMfY8X3wUH9JaNS6mkkZBpJ@9i1v3JoPsPgTC5cc593AO4iJgc6r1YfPZV0q0LfgQUt9GAEhta7MVVQ0W9y8AZdOoWmhQBdVemNUaXMLMLbqRe1orrKzAAmiQg76Exc3hQOVlpGq9s/upzNXU5CjbNibIVMEnao7RREJYoCw0MA/KlVxDlobPgYJyTl7xi4QqzExtz0YDU6CJecJ4jrOuz@6Kp3OpnOIgfGnkBhyd82BpjdQ7506EP7aX19bWx6g52@jkVlbpQEdVMMYYE0IopePINu/uojdjxDUIw@@r/uAIZXHCU@LJEUpIQmKaeHIII5awOGa@Pv@HMYZwwvnDVP72@Tu@PmckpZwlsW@ejMczhmLuyaXDeGLctyd06BfzLcoQI37MdaOu/wI)

```java
b->{                // Method with character-array as parameter and boolean return-type
  int l=b.length,   //  Length of the array
      i=l,          //  Index-integer, starting at this length
      r=0;          //  The result-sum, starting at 0
  for(;l>7&l<10     //  Start looping if the length is either 8 or 9
       &i-->0;)     //  And continue looping downwards while the index is larger than 0
      r-=           //   Decrease the result-sum by:
         (b[i]-48)  //    The current digit
         *(         //    Multiplied by:
           l-i<2?   //     If `l-i` is 1:
            1       //      Simply multiply by 1
           :        //     Else:
            i-l);   //      Multiply by `i-l`
  return r>0        //  Return if the result-sum is larger than 0,
    &r%11<1;}       //   and if the result-sum is divisible by 11
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>86</s> <s>85</s> <s>84</s> <s>83</s> <s>82</s> 79 bytes

Note: uses PHP 7.1 for negative string indices.

```
for($l=log10($a=$argn);~$c=$a[-++$x];)$s+=$x>1?$x*$c:-$c;echo$s%11<1&$l>7&$l<9;
```

Run like this:

```
echo 010464554 | php -nR 'for($l=log10($a=$argn);~$c=$a[-++$x];)$s+=$x>1?$x*$c:-$c;echo$s%11<1&$l>7&$l<9;';echo
> 1
```

## Version for PHP < 7.1 (+10 bytes)

```
echo 010464554 | php -nR 'for($l=log10($a=$argn);~$c=$a[strlen($a)-++$x];)$s+=$x>1?$x*$c:-$c;echo$s%11<1&$l>7&$l<9;';echo
```

## Explanation

```
for(
  $l=log10(         # Take the log of the input number.
    $a=$argn        # Set input to $a
  );
  ~$c=$a[-++$x];    # Iterate over digits of input (reverse). Negate to
                    # change every char to extended ASCII (all truthy),
                    # without changing empty sting (still falsy, ending
                    # the loop).
)
  $s+=$x>1?         # Add current char to the sum...
     ?$x*$c:-$c;    # multiplied by $x, unless $x is 1; subtract it.
echo
  $s%11<1 &         # Check if sum is divisible by 11, and
  $l>7   &          # log of the input is greater than 7, and
  $l<9;             # log of the input is less than 9. Outputs 0 or 1.
```

## Tweaks

- Shorter way to distinguish between empty string and `"0"`, saved a byte
- Since `10000000` is invalid, no need to compare with `greater than or equals`, `greater than` suffices, saving a byte
- Shorter way to subtract least significant digit
- Negate char instead of XOR, saving a byte
- Saved 3 bytes by using `-R` to make `$argn` available

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 58 bytes

```
iy9L[r'0r!]ppry9=[pp8[f'0-srlrpsrl`*r,]p'0-N&+[92+%!u;]]u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@z0tInukjdoEgxtqCgqNLSNrqgwCI6Td1At7gop6gASCRoFenEFgAF/NS0oy2NtFUVS61jY0ut//83NDQ0MjIyNjYGAA)

I thought this would be shorter...  There's probably room for improvement?

First part, input digits, pad with leading `0` if necessary

```
i              - input all digits (as codepoints)
 y             - push the stack size onto the stack
  9L[    !]p   - if/then block, true if <9 digits
     r'0r      - reverse stack, push 0, reverse again
            p  - pop the stack size entry off the stack
```

Second part, only process digits if we end up with 9 digits

```
r              - reverse the stack
 y             - push the stack size info the stack
  9=[pp ... ]  - if/then block, true if stack size is 9
```

Third part, process the first 8 digits

```
8[               ,]p - loop 8 times
  f                  - bring digit forward
   '0-               - convert from char to int
      s              - save digit value
       rl            - copy digit to bottom of stack
         rp          - delete from top of stack
           s         - save current loop var
            rl       - copy to bottom of stack
              `      - increment by one
               *     - multiple with current digit
                r    - reverse stack
```

Fourth part, process last digit, sum results

```
'0-     - convert digit from char to int
   N    - negate
    &+  - sum all entries on the stack
```

Fifth part, "is it zero?" and "is divisible by 11?" checks

```
[       ]   - if/then block, true is sum is non-zero
 92+        - push 11 onto the stack
    %!      - modulo math to get remainder, invert the result
      u;    - print top of stack as int, then exit
```

Last part, prints "falsey" if some success criteria wasn't met

```
u;  - print top of stack (which will be 0) and exit
```

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 88 bytes

```
$0="0"$0,n=gsub(a," ")-1{b=n-9;c=9}!b||b==1{for(d-=$n;++b<n;e=d%11)d+=$b*c--}1,$0=!e*!!d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoMwEAXQq5iQgpoMZCIVJP7DOMa6ECK0lC7Us6e@A7zpt5ViPLTXxruM9fOVenK60g3xIcg0xBnDpeQ8BeDjtb/rRDA5WitjjgvSg7lJFkbamehid3dqaZVKpYQuhD48u/4P)

And one I had fun golfing, just to abuse the flexibility of AWK.

```
$0="0"$0                             - append "0" to the input
           gsub(a," ')-1             - re-parse the input, one char per arg
        ,n=           -1             - set "n", decr RC to get number of chars
                        {         }  - code block...
                         b=n-9;      - set "b" to first char to use
                               c=9   - set "c" to initial multiplier val

!b||b==l                                   - true is we got 8 or 9 chars
        {                                } - code block...
         for(                  )           - loop over initial 8 chars
             d-=$n;                        - init: "d" set to neg of last digit
                   ++b<n;                  - test: ends after 8 chars processed
                         e=d%11            - loop-end: "e" is remainder of "%11"
                                d+=$b*c--  - loop-code: multiply and add next digit

1,           - unconditionally run implicit "print $0" code block
  $0=!e*!!d  - "$0" is 1 if accum value is non-zero and divisible by 11
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

-1 byte from @ngn's improvements

```
{(4=-2!#x)&t&~11!t:+/(|-1,2+!8)*-9#0,.'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJxdjssKgzAQRfd+hY9itWqbmUwSNfRLRLAbobRQkCwUq99eakwXvau5B+5h+npO6FpgEI1pbOIVIDB1dkneBeSYBWV6KqqI5efjuHieqedDM61D3fu+P+ru9dBJ19/uTz3qSQ9pu3imCQEAETnnoYZ2A8hJSFWiA8gRJQouHWDASJIQ9Jv8dSIGUimr3BYuoWZ2UWHJFUnhAJISFTGhHCj3uP612YvvHxM6ssvBgg/I/EQY)

Takes the input as a list of characters.

- `.'x` convert each digit to its integer (e.g. convert `"123"` to `1 2 3`)
- `-9#0,` prepend a `0`, then take the last nine values (handles padding 8-digit codes, and avoids errors on input that is not 9 digits long)
- `(|-1,2+!8)*` generate `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 -1`, and multiply the parsed digits by this
- `t:+/` take the sum, storing in variable `t`
- `t&~11!t` check that 11 evenly divides t, and that t is non-zero
- `(4=-2!#x)&` also check that the input is 8 or 9 characters long (literally: the length of the input (integer) divided by 2 is equal to 4)

Comment: `|/8 9=` -> `4=-2!`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 65 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```ruby
->n{a,*b=n.to_i.digits
i=1
b[6]&&(b[..7].sum{_1*i+=1}-a)%11<1||p}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY_PCoJAEMbvPkUERVkuzuzsrkIGXXoJEVGi2EN_SD1E-iRdJOqd6m2KdPfQXIbvB98339we5yq_tPd19KzKrRe8V97ycM3mbh4dWHlMNdvonS4LR0fg5LFMxuNJHjOmElZU-2sKrp5F0HjZdASwgLo-NX3Q6zRYx0MAQETO-TBxOoCchFQBGoAcUaLg0gAffJIkBFnLnybyQSr1i6y-1TqXGesKMeCKpLCHSImQfKEMCPoxWtmSvG9NtmUfDl_Q_de23f4A)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Looking good now, +1 from me. :) Also, I think you can change the `==0` to `<1` for -1 byte. :)

Comment: Don't forget about $. for int vars, [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZA7CsJAEIax9QZ2Iiq-suzMzu5GNGLlJUIQgygpfKBJIT4uYhNED6WnUdiIDPg3A1_xP-Z632XxIb9NgkeWLjz_OfZG6-Os14mDtUg300TMk2WS7stxaKJmsxWHQthI7LPVcQod71IX3QDO3qzdABjC6bQ9O59XqbKtTsIaACCiUqoWDeoikGVHUZE21kdGUSEa1MowKkGSIa2JO_yDRBKMtb-s7FPcmXzFTfroK0tG8xpkdZ-ktoz6hRi0fJYqxhLfVUTDl7oP5bm7bw)

Comment: @south I’m told that’s invalid in function submissions because it’s not reusable. See comments here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/563313?noredirect=1

Comment: @Jordan My understanding might be a little flawed then. Maybe I am making too many assumptions with standard I/O. Will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 114 bytes

Well this is something, `-` substracts the rest of the arguments from the first one so that handles the special case of weight `-1`. This function returns `nil` for inputs of invalid length, but on `if` clauses they operate the same as `false`. `(#{8 9}(count v))` returns `nil` if length of `v` is not 8 or 9.

```
(fn[v](if(#{8 9}(count v))(#(and(< % 0)(=(mod % 11)0))(apply -(map *(range 1 10)(reverse(map #(-(int %)48)v)))))))
```

Test cases:

```
(pprint (group-by f (map str [123456782 232262536 "010464554" 10464554 44016773 "000000000" 192837465 247594057 88888888 73 3112223342 "000000012"])))
{true  ["123456782" "232262536" "010464554" "10464554" "44016773"],
 false ["000000000" "192837465" "247594057" "88888888" "000000012"],
 nil   ["73" "3112223342"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 63 + 2 (`-F`) = 65 bytes

```perl
$F[-1]*=-1;map$s+=++$i*$_,reverse@F;say/^.{8,9}$/&&$s&&!($s%11)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FLVrXMFbLVtfQOjexQKVY21ZbWyVTSyVepyi1LLWoONXBzbo4sVI/Tq/aQseyVkVfTU2lWE1NUUOlWNXQUPP/f0NDQyMjI2Nj43/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@67oBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╪╦µΘç}<╔▼◘╞i∟~¿≥←║▐√ 4u
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%E2%95%AA%E2%95%A6%C2%B5%CE%98%C3%A7%7D%3C%E2%95%94%E2%96%BC%E2%97%98%E2%95%9Ei%E2%88%9F%7E%C2%BF%E2%89%A5%E2%86%90%E2%95%91%E2%96%90%E2%88%9A+4u&i=111222333%0A123456782%0A232262536%0A010464554%0A10464554%0A44016773%0A%0A000000000%0A192837465%0A247594057%0A88888888%0A73%0A3112223342%0A000000012&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
i%8A:byr{]ei^*mBN+|+c11%!L|A
i                               Suppress implicit eval
 %8A:b                          Length is 8 or 9 (Element #1 on the final stack)
      yr                        Reverse input
        {     m                 Map each element with
         ]e                         Its numerical value
           i^*                      Multiplied current 1-based loop index
               BN+              Negate the first element
                  |+            Sum (Element #2 on the final stack)
                    c11%!       Sum is multiple of 11 (Element #3 on the final stack)
                         L|A    Collect all the three elements and `and` them.
```

Comment: [-1](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=i%258A%3Abyr%7B]ei%5E*mBN%2B%7C%2Bc11%25%21**&i=111222333%0A123456782%0A232262536%0A010464554%0A10464554%0A44016773%0A%0A000000000%0A192837465%0A247594057%0A88888888%0A73%0A3112223342%0A000000012&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 96 bytes

```python
lambda i:7<len(i)<10*((S:=sum(a*b for a,b in zip([-1,*range(2,10)],map(int,i[::-1]))))%11<1)*S>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/NboMwEITveQpfImxEKq9/MEFJL32EHNMcjCDEEjHIkEP68hQbt6paqXOalXZnvxme0623vBjc3B7f507fq1ojU6pD11hsyAFoivGpPI6PO9Zpha69QzqrkLHowwz4vIMsddq2DWYZUHLJ7nrAxk6ZOZflDi5k0RbgACQ9vdLZn0/uMd2ePuGcAABjjHOeZCgBxoXMVcH8wDhjOZM89wMFKnIhpQhrP7wQFHKleHIpN2iRHsfGTajF6xOyrLzpsUHbEdWmRrafkGumh7OR4iVB22jD/eAWdlz1fYe/MwjZbDz3VXdjE7nplwLQnhVciVwGbqHkXlCp/FBEea9CRx4Li1AyhgD7xe85W7w@/KfDuhA6rPZvh5hByPwJ)

Similar to [@TFeld's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102500/106393), but uses Python 3.8 assignment expressions and a few other tricks to get it down to 96 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 60 bytes

```
max(length(Ans)={8,9})sum(seq(int(10fPart(expr(Ans)/₁₀^(I)))(I-2(I=1)),I,1,9
not(fPart((Ans+not(Ans))/11
```

Takes input in `Ans` as a string. Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 87 bytes

```python
lambda s:s[7:][:(q:=eval('-'+'+'.join(map('*'.join,zip('123456789',s[::-1])))))>q%11<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LbsIwFET3/gpvqpjykO/DdmJBfyTNIlWJCALHxBES/HzqqqTnbmakmbnxMZ2GQGUc5@7wOV/a69d3K5NPtfNN7dXNH4739qKKbbHOtzsPfVDXNqri/c9snn02gMTGurIqNqn2fgvN6peP2xvAHpq5G0aZZB/kEI9B6ZWXcezDpDqVdmka80ROzwCAiEQklj0USIgWDVmhQbNlY1j8C2YN1jkSekFAhSU5tkYgO1OxNk6UL0RO0usH41IC/AE)

Returns a non-empty string if the number is valid, and an empty string otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>23</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
~b*]h╒xm*Σ_A÷l£½4=ß╓
```

Outputs `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##RY2tEcJAFIQ9ZZyMurfv5xKBoBCGAQERyWAQKIqAiUakCBQm8RSRRo47JkxWfWK/3XZ/qU/n5hjj7VBs66m7X9vi0@8246sZ@uEt6/E5dY8YHREBYGa3cgQWtVAiMRgwKFtiT15MVCV3FhTxZCFk0/@TGxVKDmKaVyRoJV5D4nJOwp/D87NgGSC4Lw)

**Explanation:**

```python
~          # Dump the digits of the (implicit) input-string to the stack
 b*        # Multiply the top one by -1
   ]       # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
    h      # Push the length (without popping the list)
     ╒     # Pop and push a list in the range [1,length)
      x    # Reverse it to (length,1]
       m*  # Multiply the values in the two lists at the same positions
         Σ # Sum it together
_          # Duplicate this sum
 A÷        # Pop and check if it's divisible by 11
l£         # Push the input-length
  ½        # Integer-divide it by 2
   4=      # Check if it's equal to 4
ß          # Wrap all three values on the stack into a list
 ╓         # Pop and push the minimum
           # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```